# Javascript where clause for string that begins with text

Tags: javascript

Here is a sample of the Javascript, that I want to add an additional WHERE statement to the CONDITIONS variable.

In addition to Where Cost > 0, only include records where ProductName begins with "XYZ".
Maybe: AND ProductName StartsWith('XYZ') ??

```html
  REPORTS: [{NAME: 'MYREPORTNAME',
     CONDITIONS: 'WHERE Cost > 0',
     FIELDS: {'ProductSKU' : 'STRING',
              'ProductName' : 'STRING',
              'Cost' : 'FLOAT'  
             }
```

This is later called in this function:

```html
function retrieveMyReport(reportConfig, ClientId) {
  var fieldNames = Object.keys(reportConfig.FIELDS);
  var report = MyApp.report(
    'SELECT ' + fieldNames.join(',') +
    ' FROM ' + reportConfig.NAME + ' ' + reportConfig.CONDITIONS +
    ' DURING ' + CONFIG.DEFAULT_DATE_RANGE);
...
```

How do I expand this WHERE clause to include both conditions?

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. 1: don't use string concatenation, use [string templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). 2: what tech is this even for? Because the only db available to plain JS is IndexedDB and this is not code for working with that. 3: if this is SQL, there is nothing here that ensures a safe query, which is a giant red flag. Use a prepared statement builder instead. 4: are you _really_ asking about where clauses, or are you just asking about how to form some kind of string? Because it feels like it's the latter.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  The code is active and running, just want to do what you noted in #4 above... just asking about WHERE clauses.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No db is available to "plain JS" at all. IndexedDB is available for clientside js running in a browser, but js running in nodejs can use *any* database. (I agree with your other points, especially the one about prepared parameterised statements to avoid SQLI)

Comment: That depends on what you consider plain JS. If you consider that "the ECMAScript 262 spec" then you're absolutely right. But if you use it to mean the thing you already have because you have a browser, then there are quite a number of things that JS comes with, like IndexedDB, the DOM API, ServiceWorker, etc. In absence of a `nodejs` tag, I'm assuming anyone talking about JS is talking about the regular old plain JS that runs in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an SQL query, so you should probably use the `LIKE` operator:

```
CONDITIONS: 'WHERE Cost > 0 AND ProductName LIKE \'XYZ%\''
```